# CSS: Disable image sizing / 'cropping' an image?

Tags: css, image

I have a page with an inline-image that is about 4000px wide (good or bad practice, never mind). Is there a CSS way to 'crop' the image so it fits the viewport? Basically like `background-size: cover`, but for inline images.

As it is a responsive site, I have added this CSS rule for all images:

```
img {
  max-width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}
```

Now, for the 'cropped' image, I tried everything with `overflow`, `min-` and `max-width` & `-heigh`, but I couldn't get it to work, the browser always fits the image to the viewport. Setting a value for `min-height` even resulted in a squashed image.

Comment: `overflow: hidden;` for the parent element (e.g. `div`) does not work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

if you want to use css might aswell set the image using css:

Html:

```
<div class="img1"></div>
```

Css:

```
.img1 {
    background-image:url(yourimagepath);
    height: 200px; /** A set size*/
    width: 300px; /** A set size*/
}
```

If you have to use the image tag, than you can use the overflow property:

HTML:

```
<div class="img1">
    <img ....>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.img1 {
    height: 200px; /** A set size*/
    width: 300px; /** A set size*/
    overflow:hidden;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can wrap the `<img>` in a container to achieve the *cropped* effect.

See example: http://jsfiddle.net/amyamy86/GZzru/

HTML:

```
<div class="image">
    <img src="http://www.bubblews.com/assets/images/news/616498554_1357418372.jpg" />
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.image {
    overflow: hidden;
    height: 500px;    /* crop size */
    width: 500px;
}
```